# Single Vercel build for multiple domains + languages using @nuxtjs/i18n and Storyblok

Tags: vercel, nuxtjs3, static-site, nuxt-i18n, storyblok

I have a static website with multiple locales, that needs to be built on Vercel, using [Nuxt's Universal Rendering mode](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#universal-rendering).

The stack I'm using is:

- Nuxt 3 (Vue3)
- @nuxt/i18n
- @storyblok/nuxt

The content is fetched at build time from [Storyblok headless CMS](https://www.storyblok.com/).

Each locale has a different domain + content.

E.g.:

- exmaple.com (en-US)
- example.au (en-AU)
- example.fr (fr-FR)
  ...etc

The current setup is using multiple Vercel apps (one for each domain & locale), using the same repo  and each app has an environment variable corresponding to the default locale, this way, each app builds the website for the respective domain.

My goal is to generate the content of all the domains in a single build, since the laytout and codebase is 100% the same for each locale, instead of multiple builds for each locale.

PS: for more details, the codebase is accessible here: https://github.com/evercam/evercam-static

I tried asking questions on the Storyblok discord as well as reading multiple blog posts around the topic.